# Resolving Errno 13 Permission denied

Tags: python, permissions, anaconda

I'm trying to use the stockfish chess engine to make board evaluations through python-chess but getting permission errors.

mac os, python 3.7, Ipython through Conda 4.9.2

Here is the result with just the last line of the traceback:

```
import chess.engine
engine = chess.engine.SimpleEngine.popen_uci("/Applications/Stockfish.app")
...
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Applications/Stockfish.app'
```

I have successfully used chmod to set permissions but am still getting the error.

Please help, quite stuck on this one.

Comment: In linux, `chmod` requires root privileges, maybe that's causing a problem. Not sure for macos though, might be of help:)

Comment: Thanks for commenting. I was able to work out chmod but still getting permission denied...

Answer (score 0):

First, `Stockfish.app` is the desktop app of stockfish on Mac, not the Stockfish engine. So you need to use the engine. You can find old engines here (https://www.dropbox.com/sh/75gzfgu7qo94pvh/NlXX-QLGu6), but for the last engine, you need to install it using HomeBrew : `brew install stockfish`. See https://stockfishchess.org/download/ for more informations.

Second, in a terminal window, type `chmod +x the_stockfish_engine_path`
to disable the permission restriction.